# Are sound waves in the cochlea transverse or longitudinal?

Tags: acoustics

Soundwaves are typically shown as transverse in the cochlea, but surely they would be longitudinal? Are they shown as transverse because its easier to draw only?

Comment: Fluids can't support transverse waves, so I think something is off here.

Comment: What do you mean by *"shown as transverse"*? If you mean that people draw a sinusoidal graph then then you may misunderstand the relationship between graphs and waves. The graph of a longitudinal wave still have the variation (in this case pressure variation) graphed at right angles to the independent axis.

Comment: Do you mean the motion of the basilar membrane maybe?

Comment: See the first answer here maybe https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174082/46512